# Wix-code data from non-secured site

Tags: jquery, fetch, velo

Is there anyway to use fetch or any other method to get data from a http not https data file? I keep trying to use the wix-fetch in code editor, but always fails

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://support.wix.com/en/article/accessing-3rd-party-services) in the Wix Code documentation:

> Note: You cannot request HTTP content from a service if your site is
>   an HTTPS site. Invalid requests will cause an error that you can see
>   using your browser's developer tools. To fix the request, you can
>   either use the HTTPS protocol to fetch the requested resources from
>   you HTTPS site or you can turn off SSL on your site to fetch an HTTP
>   resource.